# How to multiply B1 with C1, B2 with C2, Bn with Cn and Sum them?

Tags: excel

This is my sheet:

```
Goods Type  Quantity / Geram    Gold Price 750K Price of Exchange
Gold        100                 1,554.00        0
Silver      500                 235.00          0
Euro        200                 0.00            1.01
Pond        50                  0.00            0.97
Gold        100                 1,554.00        0
Silver      500                 235.00          0
Euro        200                 0.00            1.00
Pond        50                  0.00            0.99
```

I want to do to this:

If `Goods Type` is `Gold`: multiply `Quantity / Geram` by `Gold Price`.

In my case it should be: `(100 * 1554) + (100 * 1554)` = `310800`, and if I add more entries in the future, it should add more.

I have this cell in my current sheet: If `Goods Type` is `Gold`, then `sumif` all `Quantity / Geram` in another cell which is now `200`.

Comment: Have a look at sumproduct().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`: [sumproduct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A9="Gold")*B2:B9*C2:C9)
```

It multiplies TRUE/FALSE (result of `A2:A9="Gold"`) with quantity and price and sums everything (in this case = 155400 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 15540 + 0 + 0 + 0))

Result:

[image]

Adjust ranges to your data.

Comment: Doesn't sumproduct() use separators like "," or ";" between the arrays?

Comment: Yes, it does. But =SUMPRODUCT(TRUE,1) = 0 while =SUMPRODUCT(TRUE*1)=1 or =SUMPRODUCT(--TRUE,1)=1 . Don't know if [microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) is a good source for best practice, but basic examples are with *

Comment: So you are the source for best practice? Or Microsoft who coded it??

Comment: My answer to question is with exact same practice as in Microsoft example - using *

Comment: "Don't know if microsoft is a good source for best practice" you cast doubt on Microsoft with your comment which is what I was querying - quoted here just in case comments get "lost"...

Comment: No, "Don't know if microsoft is a good source for best practice" is a doubt on myself since my sources are limited.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `SumProduct()` for three columns, so you can create an `IF()` formula for getting 1 in case of "Gold" and 0 else. This leads to following kind of formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2:A6="Gold",1,0),B2:B6,C2:C6)
```

See following screenshot:

[image]